# subsetting a dataframe by comparing columns

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I would like to use R to merge some files based on the values of some
parameters. I am using the following csv file

```
ls table.csv  
filename,type,rep,category,param
file1,1,4,A,1
file2,3,1,B,1
file3,2,1,A,2
file4,1,1,C,3
file5,1,1,C,2
file6,2,2,D,1
file7,3,1,C,2
file8,3,1,B,3
file9,3,1,B,3
file10,1,4,A,1
file11,1,1,B,1

ta <- readr::read_csv("table.csv")
Parsed with column specification:
cols(
filename = col_character(),
type = col_integer(),
rep = col_integer(),
category = col_character(),
param = col_integer()
)
```

I would like to merge the files that have identical values for
ta$type, ta$rep and ta$category (ta$param is irrelevant).

So I would merge: file1, file10 [1,4,A] file2, file8, file9 [3,1,B]
file4, file5 [1,1,C] file3 [2,1,A], file6 [2,2,D], file7 [3,1,C] and
file11[1,1,B] will not be merged with any other files.

Does anyone has any ideas how to do this ? Thanks !

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Three new concatenated files (file1+file10, file2+file8+file9 and file4+file5)

Comment: Not clear from the comments

Comment: I would like to end up with three output files, newfile1 <- rbind(file1, file10), newfile2 <- rbind(file2, file8, file9) ...etc

Comment: Your question would greatly benefit from some additional formatting where you are referring to code or data constructs, such as: `fileX [a, b, c]`. It will make it easier for people to understand your question and help.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. What I really meant was that the files that have identical attributes for type, rep and category should be concatenated so in this case file1 and file10 would be merged, as well as file2, file8, file9 and finally file4 and file5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option is to use `dplyr::group_by` on columns (`type, rep, category`) and then `summarise` using `paste0` with `collapse="+"` argument. The solution will be as:

```
library(readr)

library(dplyr)

ta <- readr::read_csv("table.csv")

ta %>% group_by(type, rep, category) %>%
  summarise(file = paste0(filename, collapse="+"))


# # A tibble: 7 x 4
# # Groups: type, rep [?]
#    type   rep category file             
#   <int> <int> <chr>    <chr>            
# 1     1     1 B        file11           
# 2     1     1 C        file4+file5      
# 3     1     4 A        file1+file10     
# 4     2     1 A        file3            
# 5     2     2 D        file6            
# 6     3     1 B        file2+file8+file9
# 7     3     1 C        file7
```